# HTML and CSS within Bootstrap tooltips not working in new version

Tags: html, css, security, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I was wondering if the following is a bug or a vulnerability fix? This worked fine in version 4.1.0:

```html
<i class="ex" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true">
    <span style="font-family:cardo">someText</span>
</i>
```

In version 4.3.1 the css within the span (font-family) does not work anymore i.e. the HTML is still rendered but the CSS styling is completely lost (when you inspect the tooltip it just shows: `<span>someText</span>` whereas `style="font-family:cardo"` is just lost. Is this a bug or is this connected to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases (Fixed an XSS vulnerability (CVE-2019-8331) in our tooltip and popover plugins by implementing a new HTML sanitizer)?

Comment: Can u pleae describe `does not work anymore` any further? What exactly appears on your screen? Is the HTML visible as text (which would point to the new sanitizer)? Is the styling just ignored (which would point to some problem with the styles) ? Please provide more info

Comment: I edited the question accordingly. So the styling is not just ignored but deleted!

Comment: Seems like this could actually be related to the new sanitizer as it looks like the style attribute is beign removed.

Comment: well, ok. but this means it is actually a feature and not a bug? So anyone who needs CSS in a tooltip has to find other ways around it?